# numpy find average from class instances (iterate through elements of instances)

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array full with many class instances

```
a = np.array([[A(2, 10)], [A(3, 15)], [A(4, 14)]])
```

How can I calculate using numpy the average of the  first `A` indices only.

Hence, the average of 2, 3, 4?

One way is:

```
thenew = np.zeros((a.size, a.size))
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
    thenew[idx] = a[idx].a

result = np.average(thenew[:,0])
```

but I am looking for a better solution using numpy.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np

class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class B():

    def __init__(self, c, d, the_a):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.the_a = the_a

    def method(self, the_a):
        thenew = np.zeros((self.the_a.size, self.the_a.size))
        for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(self.the_a):
            thenew[idx] = self.the_a[idx].a

        return np.average(thenew[:,0])

a = np.array([[ A(2, 4)], [A(3,5)], [A(4,4)]])
b = B(1,1,a)
print(b.method(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list from all attributes `a` and and average them:

```
>>> np.average([x[0].a for x in a]) 
3.0
```

The list comprehension is faster than `np.vectorize` for this use case:

```
%timeit np.average([x[0].a for x in a])
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 µs per loop
```

vs.

```
%%timeit
func = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.a)
np.average(func(a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!I just want to ask by the way, how indexing works in this case.I mean , the `x[0].a` gives us the first elements,ok.Would we ever use `x[1].a`?(upvoted)

Comment: No,  you need the `x[0]` because your instances are in `[]`, i.e. `[A(2, 10)]`. Use `np.average([x[0].b for x in a]) ` for the second element. Unless you put multiple instances in the sub-list (second dimension):  `[A(2, 10),  A(3, 15)]`.

Comment: Oh,yes.I would use `x[1]` if I had `[A(2,10) , A(3,4)]`

Comment: Hi, if you can help with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067429/handle-multid-data-str-object-is-not-callable) I 'll appreciate!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy's counterpart from the python map function: [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
    func = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.a)
    np.average(func(a))
```